# how to find the least number of operations to compute x^n

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, np-complete

here is the problem from

> ACM International Collegiate
>   Programming Contest Asia Regional
>   Contest, Yokohama, 2006-11-05

Starting with x and repeatedly multiplying by `x`, we can compute `x^31` with thirty multiplications:

```
x^2 = x * x, x^3 = x^2 * x, x^6 = x^3 * x^3, x^7 = x^6 *x, x^14 = x^7 * x^7 ,
x^15 = x^14 * x, x^30 = x^15 * x^15 , x^31 = x^30 * x
```

write a program to find the least number of operations to compute `x^n`
by multiplication and division starting with `x` for the given positive integer `n` and `n<=200`

for n = 31 the least #operations is 6 
for n = 50 the least #operations is 7

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes - exponentiation by squaring will not use the minimum number of operations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation

There is no efficient algorithm that will get you the minimum number of steps, and dynamic programming does not work.

I am guessing that `n` is small enough to allow a brute force solution to pass, although it might need to be optimized. Do you know how to brute force it?

Comment: +1 Oooh, shiny! I guess I've got my "new thing learned" for the day. Pity it's NP-complete though :(

Comment: Yep, I think a lot of people will learn something interesting today :) +1 too

Comment: since it's NP complete, and n's domain is reasonably small, compile a table, and just do lookups...

Comment: I don't think the NP-Hardness for finding the shortest chain for a _single_ exponent is known.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
long long int pow(long long int, long long int);
int count=0;

int main()
{
    long long int a,b;
    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%lld %lld",&a,&b);
    pow(a,b);
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}

long long int pow(long long int a, long long int b)
{
    count++;
    if(b==0)
    return 1;
    long long int res=pow(a,b/2);
    if(b%2)
    return res*res*a;
    else
    return res*res;
}
```